# Magento Core doesnt work after transfer

Tags: magento2, php, cli, transfer

Hello i just put my store to other new server but i have very big problems... 
I set right permissions ( owner and group too ) to magento dir but i get this error

> Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: No such entity. in
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php:102
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(204):
> Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository->getById('0') #1
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(135):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getWebsite('0') #2
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Website.php(30):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getWebsite('0') #3
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49):
> Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Website->getScope('0') #4
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(87):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('website',
> '0') #5
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(63):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig() #6
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #7
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(60):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get() #8
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #9
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(292):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #10
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(191):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() #11
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(152):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default')
>
> ## 12 /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131):
>
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/newreli...') #13
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/newreli...') #14
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Config.php(91):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('newrelicreporti...') #15
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Plugin/HttpPlugin.php(49):
> Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config->isNewRelicEnabled() #16
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121):
> Magento\NewRelicReporting\Plugin\HttpPlugin->beforeCatchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception)) #17
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
> Object(Exception)) #18
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(39):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('catchException',
> Array, Array) #19
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
> Object(Exception)) #20
> /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/index.php(39):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 21 {main}

Also when im trying to make rollback database cli shows me

> Maintenance mode already enabled You are about to remove current code
> and/or database tables. Are you sure?[y/N]y DB rollback is starting...
> No such entity. Skipped disabling maintenance mode

I have over 14k items in my db and im freaky out.

Comment: Have you removed generated folder and run all commands like di compile and setup upgrade,s:s:d?

Comment: well no i didnt use any of this :S can we talk for a while via chat?

Comment: [Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException]
  No such entity.
for all commands like bin/magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly please remove generated, cache and page cache folder

> rm -rf generated/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/*

and then run below commands:

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (if you are using developer mode please add -f)
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

after running all the commands please refresh your site and check